# Swift Design Pattern. Why did they include Any, AnyObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, design-patterns

I've recently moved to Swift from regular objc. And yes, I know how to use `Any` and `AnyObject`.

But I'm curious why Apple decided on `AnyObject` and `Any`. Why is it good? What problem is it solving? How much developer time is it saving?

Comment: First idea that comes to mind: many existing Objective-C APIs employ `id` and that had to be mapped somehow.

Comment: If there is no AnyObject, what could be the type of delegate object ?

Answer (score 7):

For backward compatibility with existing Cocoa libraries. Classes like `NSDictionary`, `NSArray`, etc. do not enforce type on all objects contained. Also in Obj-C there's `id` which is a pointer to any Obj-C object.